# writing files / large amount of bytes fails

Tags: java, sockets, byte, datainputstream, dataoutputstream

I am writing files / large amount of bytes over socket.

But lets say I am writing bytes. I do this;

```
//Connection.data is a dataoutputstream
byte[] a = new byte[filelength];
//load file into the array
//write file
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
Connection.data.writeByte(a[i]);                                              
}
```

To receive:

```
//dat is a datainputstream
byte[] byteA = new byte[bytestoread]
for (int i = 0; i < toread; i++) {
        byteA[i] = dat.readByte();
}
```

I do log the incoming data, and lets say if the file is 200000 bytes, it stops at around 199990 bytes etc. Basically, any size of the byte[], and it will
 stop at the last bytes, and time out. I will explain more if you dont understand. Thanks.

Comment: Writing one byte at a time can be very inefficient. I would suggest writing blocks of data at a time. e.g. 512 bytes to 32KB.

Comment: Same problem there. Thats why I tried this method.

Comment: In either case you need to make sure you are flushing the data.

Comment: Where does 'bytestoread' come from?

Comment: It prints out before sending all data the size of incoming data, file size.

Comment: So how does the receiver read the printout?

Comment: Yes. It does. Can I use like other ways of writing to make it work better?

Comment: @user1624309 is this for your virus on hackforums.net?

Comment: ? no this is not for virus and I dont hack

Comment: @user1624309 okay [redpois0n](http://www.hackforums.net/showthread.php?tid=2782604).

Comment: Could you post the complete code, with all the variable initialization and stream closing etc.

Comment: works in most cases but sometimes suddenly wont work. Localhost is sometimes fine, but otherwise no

Comment: instead of using a dataoutputstream and datainputstream, can you use a BufferedOutputStream and BufferedInputStream, and post the results ?

Comment: I did using buffereds. Works better but still fails after a while.

Answer (score 3):

When you have finished writing you need to call [`flush`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#flush%28%29) to ensure that the bytes are actually sent.

```
Connection.data.flush();
```

From the documentation:

> Flushes this data output stream. This forces any buffered output bytes
>   to be written out to the stream.
>
> The flush method of DataOutputStream
>   calls the flush method of its underlying output stream.

Comment: No its not that. Still writes successfully, but it reads and stops around 100-10 bytes until end.